# ng-option showing two empty options while group by empty value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

I have made dropdown with ng-option and added grouping.
Data contains empty string for some opting on which i have added grup by.
It show two empty nodes in dropdown.
Need to remove those two empty nodes from dropdown

```
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [{
      name: 'black',
      shade: ''
    }, {
      name: 'white',
      shade: 'light',
      notAnOption: true
    }, {
      name: 'red',
      shade: 'dark'
    }, {
      name: 'blue',
      shade: 'dark',
      notAnOption: true
    }, {
      name: 'yellow',
      shade: 'light',
      notAnOption: false
    }];
    $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
  }]);
```

Html:

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in colors">
  </select>
```

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/LUCYUdnJVl2tLGKYkXD4)

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: Of course there is empty option, because you have `shade: ''`.

Comment: you can't have a blank `optgroup`.  it is creating an optgroup row for the `''` shade, then creating a second optgroup for `black`, because the `''` optgroup doesn't have a value and therefore can't be tracked.

Comment: Need to remove those two empty option values from the dropdown without adding any other optgroup.

Comment: is it possible to remove those two fields or i need to make change in my JSON?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Remove `shade: ''`.

Comment: @Gagan -  you can remove the unwanted items by creating/applying a custom filter to your ng-options.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *remove* those empties shades of colors.

Just include this in your controller:

```
$scope.colors = $scope.colors.map(function(value) {
  if (value.shade == '') {
    value.shade = undefined;
  }
  return value;
});
```